# What to do when "status-completed' answer does not work (anymore)?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

The following thread:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications

has an official answer (from Jeff Atwood♦) which says:

> There is a checkbox to opt out of favorite notifications now on the preferences tab of the user page.

I couldn't find the cited checkbox option (did I miss something?). Since it is a 3.5 year old thread this feature can have changed (here are [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52098/option-to-opt-out-of-certain-favorite-questions) [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55547/how-to-disable-you-have-5-favorite-changes-see-your-favorites) old threads marked as duplicates from the previous one).

Regarding situations where **[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) answer does not work anymore, what is more appropriate action to take** if one wishes to update/solve/suggest the subject:

Some options I can think of are:

- ask another question and explain why it is being asked again,
- put a bounty in the original thread and ask for updated answers,
- flag for moderator attention, request a rettag and edit the accepted-answer emphasizing it is outdated,
- leave a comment to the OP asking him/her to remove the accepted-answer status,
- combinations of above, other?.

<sub>This is not the main question, but I would also appreciate any guidance about how to do to stop receiving favorites notifications.</sub>

Comment: The thread (used as example) is deleted now and the bounty was returned. The former duplicates are still marked as duplicates. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a bounty with the reason `Current answers are outdated`

[image: bounty reasons]

Comment: Just did it. Hope it works.